# Title format and unnumbered sections

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, titles, chapters

I'm writing a report that requires a particular style for titles as given by:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\fontsize{22pt}{0}}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE\thechapter\\
~}
```

This shows up as intended below:

[image: Introduction]

However, for my 'References' and 'Glossary' sections, a number shows up in the heading despite them being unnumbered.

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}References}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
```

[image: References]

Even a "test" chapter* has a number (also 7).

```
\chapter*{test}
```

[image: test section]

Does anyone know how I might go about rectifying this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem comes from the placement of the chapter label as the last argument of `\titleformat`. Here is a correct placement. Note  the style you have to use is `\display` instead of the default `hang`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{22pt}{28pt}\bfseries}{\LARGE\thechapter}{1.5ex}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Test}

\lipsum[2-3]

 \cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}References}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that posting this in the document before the needed section helped solve my problem:

```
\titleformat
{\chapter}
{\fontsize{22pt}{0}}
{}
{0em}
{\bf\LARGE}
```

Comment: This is wrong syntax and will create problems for you later. `\bf` is a depreciated command its own problems. Use Bernhard's solution, which is the _correct_ way doing this.